# jQuery Validation plugin - How to display all messages for all rules at once?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

```
    rules: {
        zip: {
            digits: true,
            maxlength: 4
        }
    },
    messages: {
        zip: {
            digits: "non-digit",
            maxlength: "too-long"
        }
    },
```

I have something above, but if I enter

aaaa11, I expect the two error messages but I only get the "non-digit" message. If I swap the two rules above, I get the "too-long" message.

What I want though is both of them AT THE SAME TIME, how to do it? Thanks

Comment: AFAIK, this is impossible.  You would have to re-write the plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quote OP:**

> *"What I want though is both of them AT THE SAME TIME, how to do it?"*

You can't.  [This is not a feature of the plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/).

The rules are examined in the same order in which you've declared them.  If you have three rules on one particular field, the second and third rule will not be examined until the first rule is satisfied.  However, when a field also includes the `required` rule, it is *always* examined *before* the other rules, regardless of order.

There is only one error `label` element created per each field being validated and its content is replaced and/or hidden as needed.  There is no way, without re-writing the plugin, to get the various messages from all the rules to display at the same time.

---

Depending on your situation, you *might* want to do something like this...

```
rules: {
    zip: {
        digits: true,
        maxlength: 4
    }
},
messages: {
    zip: "must contain only digits and no more than 4 characters"
},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Zqc6D/

Comment: Thought so :( Messages like above can be a little misleading sometimes though. Maybe I'll just stick to manual if-else conditions since the form is only validated ON SUBMIT. Thanks for clearing this up sir.